# Angular 6 , Send Variable from service to component

Tags: angular, angular6

I want to pass the result of a function on my service, to my component.

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class passVarHelper {

  header: string;

  constructor() {
    this.header = "Title";
  }


  passindexToHeader(index:string) {
    this.header = index;
    this.takeindexToHeader();
  }

  takeindexToHeader() {
    return this.header;
  }
}
```

**And receive the result on this function in my component:**

```
loadIndex() {
  this.indexSelected = this._passVarHelper.takeindexToHeader();
}
```

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a function from a service in Angular you will want to pass that service into your component

```
// component.ts
constructor( private myService: passVarHelper ){ }

public loadIndex() {
    this.indexSelected = this.myService.takeindexToHeader();
}
```

Comment: yes but when i change the Header, the component dont refresh

Comment: @user3562198 If you want your component to *receive a notification* when there is a change, you should declare an [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables) in your service and subscribe to it from your Component. [Here](https://netbasal.com/event-emitters-in-angular-13e84ee8d28c#e576) is an example.